# ResourceBundle only understands "en" locale

Tags: java, locale

I create a locale, and try to create a ResourceBundle using said locale. If I use a finnish locale, ResourceBundle doesn't seem to accept/understand it - instead it gets a null locale. When using an english locale, it seems to work just fine.

```
Locale obj = new Locale("en");
ResourceBundle resource = ResourceBundle.getBundle("web_resources", obj);
log.debug(resource.getLocale());
log.debug(obj);
```

Logs "en", "en".

```
Locale obj = new Locale("fi");
ResourceBundle resource = ResourceBundle.getBundle("web_resources", obj);
log.debug(resource.getLocale());
log.debug(obj);
```

Logs "", "fi".

I've also tested fr (french) and german (de) locales - they don't work either. Adding country codes didn't seem to help. What am I missing?

Comment: Which files do you actually have in your application to support this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem a month or so ago. The resource file had the wrong character encoding. If I remember correctly, the file is supposed to be in UTF-8, but at some point the encoding had changed to ISO 8859-4.

A silly mistake, but nevertheless a valuable lesson learned.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a web_resources_fi.class of web_resources_fi.properties in the root of your classpath? If not, then ResourceBundle.getBundle looks for web_resources.class or web_resources.properties (after looking for such files with the default locale appended to the base name).

See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29 for details about how this method works.

Comment: I have web_resources.properties, web_resources_en.properties, *_fi.properties and *_fi_FI.properties. I changed something in the *_en.properties file to make sure it's the file that's loaded and not some other file in an obscure location. It was.